# Catch click event on class added by jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, onclick

Do I need to do anything special to catch the click event of an element that was added to the dom via jquery,

I add the following to the dom:

```
$('.dvPagerCities > .pagination > ul > li > a').addClass("pageCities")
```

Which display in the html via chrome as

```
<a class="pageCities">»</a>
```

But when I try to catch the click event no alert is displayed.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.pageCities').click(function () {
            alert('City click detected');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

--------------Update---------------

```
<script>
    $('.dvPagerCities > .pagination > ul > li > a').addClass("pageCities")
    $(function () {
        $(".getCities").click(function () {
            var city = $(this).text();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("pvDisplayListOfWeatherCities", "Weather")',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { id: $(this).attr("dataCountry")},
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (result) {
                    //alert('Country click detected'),
                    $('Title').text('Cities in ' + city),
                    $('#dvFullPage').remove();
                    $('#dvPartial').html(result);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });


</script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.dvPagerCities').on('click', '.pageCities', function () {

            alert('City click detected');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

----------------HTML Added--------------

```
<div class="dvPagerCities">
<div class="pagination">
<ul>
<li class="PagedList-skipToPrevious">
<a href="/Weather/Index/Australia?p=1" class="pageCities">«</a>
</li>
<li class="disabled PagedList-pageCountAndLocation">
<a class="pageCities">Page 2 of 2.</a>
</li>
<li class="disabled PagedList-skipToNext">
<a class="pageCities">»</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

-----------------Extra Info------------------

Ok if I click on link and go to weather page, then click on country and display list of cities for that country and try to page nothing happens, I get a full page refresh.

BUT if I then click on page link again, I get alert.

Why is class not getting picked up on when cities 1st appears and takes a full page update before click is detected

Comment: You need to delegate to something that you can target before the class is added

Comment: It is working I think check here http://jsfiddle.net/cnsJP/ , You have write `javascript code` after creating the element.

Comment: You are adding a class, not an HTML element... Show us the way you've added it..

Comment: @writeToBhuwan the way is shown

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your `<script>` executes *before* the `.pageCities` class gets added, the `.click` method has nothing to find and won't bind to anything.  Make sure that `.pageCities` is added first, or use event delegation:

```
$(".dvPagerCities").on('click', '.pageCities', function () {
```

Comment: `.pagination` might be a viable delegate as well

Comment: Hi still does not work, I've updated my jquery code to show what i'm doing.